# How do ‘arpack’, ‘propack’ and ‘lobpcg’ compare to each other?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, svd

I want to implement singular value decomposition on a sparse matrix using the Scipy implementation. The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.linalg.svds.html) shows three solvers: ‘arpack’, ‘propack’ and ‘lobpcg’. How do these solvers compare in terms of performance and running time?

Comment: Can't you test that yourself?

Comment: I could. Yet, a simple evaluation wouldn't give me a comprehensive and trustworthy insight and testing/evaluation on various datasets takes much time.